# Parsing data returned from server using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, what is the data type returned?

Tags: swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I hope I manage to ask this properly:
I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON for managing the JSON files I get from the server.
I have issues with understanding the type of `response.result.value` , how to cast it to an object I can construct it with SwiftyJSON's `JSON(data: data)` constructor.
This is my code for the request using Alamofire:

```
func performRequest() {
    //        parameters["retry_count"] = retryNum
    if let _ = host, let path = path {

        let request = Alamofire.request(HOST + path, method: method, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
        request.responseJSON { response in

            print("-----")
            print(response.response?.statusCode)
            print("-----")

            // check if responseJSON already has an error
            // e.g., no network connection
            if let json = response.result.value {

                print("--------")
                print(json)
                print("--------")
            }
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                self.completionHandler?(response.result.isSuccess, nil)
                self.retryRequest()
                return
            }

                // make sure we got JSON and it's a dictionary
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("didn't get dictionary object as JSON from API")
                self.completionHandler?(response.result.isSuccess, nil)
                self.retryRequest()
                return
            }

            // make sure status code is 200
            guard response.response?.statusCode == 200 else {
                // handle status code

                self.completionHandler?(response.result.isSuccess, nil)
                return
            }

            self.completionHandler?(response.result.isSuccess, json)
            RequestsQueue.sharedInstance.sema.signal()

        }
    }
```

This results with this print:

```
{
numOfShiftsInDay = 3;
shifts =     (
            {
        endTime = "14:00";
        startTime = "07:30";
    },
            {
        endTime = "20:00";
        startTime = "13:30";
    },
            {
        endTime = "02:00";
        startTime = "19:30";
    }
);
```

}

this data type is a `[String: AnyObject]`.

I want to use it to construct a SwiftyJSON JSON object since it is easier for me to parse the data using SwiftyJSON methods..

This is the code I try for parsing it and then using it but obviously it doesn't work:

```
            let json = JSON(data: data)
```

I get this compilation error:

```
 Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

So how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  `JSON(data)` instead of `JSON(data: data)` because this `init(data:)` wants `Data` as argument.

**Changed line**

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
```

**To**

```
let json = JSON(data)
```

Comment: Works. How simple is that